# Not able to insert a specific segment from an array via php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a webpage I am making that will enable a user to create a series of questions for an online quiz. The page is working for the most part except I have one issue I can not figure out.

The issue is that when I click save the questions and answers are saved correctly but their is a checkbox that is used to indicate if the answer is the correct answer or not and that is not being saved correctly. What is happening is if I have three questions the it saves the first three potential answers for the first question all have the "yes" value saved in their row and I am not sure why.

Below is my PHP code to grab the info from the form and insert into a mysql via php

```
//if save was clicked
if(isset($_POST['saveit']))
{
    $tmodnameid = $_POST['tmodnameid'];
    $tmodnameid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $tmodnameid);

    mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs(tmoduleid, quiz_createdon, quiz_created_by) VALUES('$tmodnameid','$timedate_rightnowis','$myuid')");
    $quizid = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);

    //lets save all the questions and answers. Each question can potentially have 6 answers
    $n = 0;
    $newquestion = $_POST['newquestion'];
    foreach($newquestion as $aquestion)
    { 

        mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_questions(quizid, qquestion) VALUES('$quizid','$aquestion')");
        $questionrowid = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);

        //lets save each of this questions answers

        //save first potential answer for this question
        $answera = $_POST['answera'][$n];
        $isanswera = $_POST['isanswera'][$n];
        mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) VALUES('$questionrowid','$answera','$isanswera')");

        //save second potential answer for this question
        $answerb = $_POST['answerb'][$n];
        $isanswerb = $_POST['isanswerb'][$n];
        mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerb','$isanswerb')");

        //save third potential answer for this question
        $answerc = $_POST['answerc'][$n];
        $isanswerc = $_POST['isanswerc'][$n];
        mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerc','$isanswerc')");

        //save fourth potential answer for this question
        $answerd = $_POST['answerd'][$n];
        $isanswerd = $_POST['isanswerd'][$n];
        mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerd','$isanswerd')");

        //save fifth potential answer for this question
        $answere = $_POST['answere'][$n];
        $isanswere = $_POST['isanswere'][$n];
        mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) VALUES('$questionrowid','$answere','$isanswere')");

        //save sixth potential answer for this question
        $answerf = $_POST['answerf'][$n];
        $isanswerf = $_POST['isanswerf'][$n];
        mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerf','$isanswerf')");

        $n++;
    }

    //get rid of any blank rows that were created 
    mysqli_query($dbc, "DELETE from training_quizs_answers WHERE answer=''");
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>                
            <h4>Success!</h4>
            You successfully setup a new quiz from the training module.
        </div>";

    }
```

My HTML is below. I have a javascript that enables a user to click a button and dynamically add as many question/answer text boxes as needed.

```
<head>
          <script language="javascript">
fields = 2;
function addInput() {
if (fields != 50) {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<br /><br />" + fields +") Question<br />    <textarea name='newquestion[]' /></textarea><br />ANSWERS:<br /><div style='float:left;     padding-right:20px'> A) <input type='text' name='answera[]' size='90'/></div><div     style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswera[]'     value='yes'> is answer</div><br style='clear:both'><div style='float:left; padding-right:20px'> B) <input type='text' name='answerb[]' size='90'/></div><div style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerb[]' value='yes'> is answer</div><br style='clear:both'/><div style='float:left; padding-right:20px'> C) <input type='text' name='answerc[]' size='90'/></div><div style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerc[]' value='yes'> is answer</div> <br style='clear:both'/><div style='float:left; padding-right:20px'> D) <input type='text' name='answerd[]' size='90'/></div><div style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerd[]' value='yes'> is answer</div><br style='clear:both'/><div style='float:left; padding-right:20px'> E) <input type='text' name='answere[]' size='90'/></div><div style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswere[]' value='yes'> is answer</div><br style='clear:both'/><div style='float:left; padding-right:20px'> F) <input type='text' name='answerf[]' size='90'/></div><div style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerf[]' value='yes'> is answer</div><br /><br style='clear:both'>";
fields += 1;
} else {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<br />Only 50 questions are able to be     created.";
document.form.add.disabled=true;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='form1' id='form1'>
    <div class="row-form clearfix">
        <div class="span4">
            Training Module Name 
            <select name='tmodnameid'>
            <?php
                //lets select all training modules that have not quiz yet
                $tlistsql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT tmoduleid, tmodule_name FROM training_modules WHERE tmodule_quizid='' ORDER by tmodule_name desc");
                while($tlistrow = mysqli_fetch_array($tlistsql))
                {
                    $tmoduleid = $tlistrow['tmoduleid'];
                    $tmodule_name = stripslashes($tlistrow['tmodule_name']);
                    echo "<option value='$tmoduleid'>$tmodule_name</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="row-form clearfix">
        <input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add Question" />
        <br />
        <br />
        1) Question
        <br />
        <textarea name='newquestion[]' /></textarea>
        <br />
        ANSWERS:
        <br />
        <div style='float:left; padding-right:20px'> A) <input type='text' name='answera[]' size='90'/></div>
        <div style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswera[]' value='yes'> is answer</div>
        <br style='clear:both'>

        <div style='float:left; padding-right:20px'> B) <input type='text' name='answerb[]' size='90'/></div>
        <div style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerb[]' value='yes'> is answer</div>
        <br style='clear:both'/>

        <div style='float:left; padding-right:20px'> C) <input type='text' name='answerc[]' size='90'/></div>
        <div style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerc[]' value='yes'> is answer</div>
        <br style='clear:both'/>

        <div style='float:left; padding-right:20px'> D) <input type='text' name='answerd[]' size='90'/></div>
        <div style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerd[]' value='yes'> is answer</div>
        <br style='clear:both'/>

        <div style='float:left; padding-right:20px'> E) <input type='text' name='answere[]' size='90'/></div>
        <div style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswere[]' value='yes'> is answer</div>
        <br style='clear:both'/>

        <div style='float:left; padding-right:20px'> F) <input type='text' name='answerf[]' size='90'/></div>
        <div style='float:left; padding-top:20px!important'> <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerf[]' value='yes'> is answer</div>
        <br /><br style='clear:both'>
        <div id='text'>

        </div>                          
    </div>

    <div class="footer tar">
        <input type='submit' name='saveit' value='Save' is='submit' class='btn'></form>
    </div>            
</body>
```

Comment: I think you meant "there is a checkbox", not "their is a checkbox".

Comment: Thanks for the grammar correction. Any code suggestions? ;)

Comment: Only checked boxes are submitted in a form. So `$_POST['answera'][0]` is not the checkbox from the first row, it's the first checkbox that's checked.

Comment: Ahh yes. So based on my code how might I identify which answer had a "yes" in its checkbox. each question has 6 potential answers and only one of the 6 check boxes will have a 'yes' value for any given set of questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unchecked boxes will post nothing, as if they did not exist. There's a lot that can be done to tighten up your code but I won't go all out here. A quick fix is to set explicit keys for your checkbox `name` values:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='isanswere[0]' value='yes'>
<input type='checkbox' name='isanswere[1]' value='yes'>
<input type='checkbox' name='isanswere[2]' value='yes'>
etc.
```

That way `$_POST['isanswere'][$n];` will correspond to the checkbox you think. I would suggest doing the same for your answer fields as well.

Comment: So one more question. 
I tried doing 

    $answera = $_POST['answera'][$n];
    $answera = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $answera);
    $isanswera = $_POST['isanswera'][$n];
    $isanswera = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $isanswera);  

How should I sanatize the $_post[] since the mysqli_real_escape_string() does not work because the posts are arrays?

Comment: I think you may need to check if that key exists or you'll get a reference error in php: `$isanswere = array_key_exists($n, $_POST['isanswere']);`